# Dynamic date renders differently in email preview than send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are dynamically setting text to show the last day of the previous month. This is the AMPscript in use:

```
%%[ 

SET @CurrentDate = NOW(1) 
SET @Month = DatePart(@CurrentDate, 'M') 
SET @Year = DatePart(@CurrentDate, 'Y') 

SET @FirstOfMonth = DateParse(Concat('01/', @month, '/', @year)) 
SET @PreviousMonth = DateAdd(@FirstOfMonth, -1, "D") 

]%%
```

Then in the body it's formatted and output as:

```
%%=Format(@PreviousMonth, 'MMMM dd, yyyy')=%%
```

In the email preview this shows correctly as 'October 31, 2019'

When doing a test or guided send, we see 'January 10, 2019'

It looks like it's mixing up the days/months, but why would this be different from a preview to a test/live send? Is this something determined by a user/sender setting?

Comment: Outside of figuring out this issue (I know that SFMC has issues with day first dates as inputs) couldn't you just change your `@FirstOfMonth` var to be: `SET @FirstOfMonth = DateParse(Concat(@month,'/'01/',@year))` and resolve the whole problem?

Comment: @Gortonington that would fix the send but break the preview. Not a big deal for me personally, but the it doesn't give the customer confidence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like an ampscript bug... it's possibly based on if they think the running user would do MM/DD or DD/MM but you're better of just formatting it differently.

Your string ends up being DD/MM/YYYY while the string in the DateParse reference is YYYY/MM/DD. The easiest thing to do would just be to change
`SET @FirstOfMonth = DateParse(Concat('01/', @month, '/', @year))` to `SET @FirstOfMonth = DateParse(Concat(@year, '/', @month, '/01'))`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DateParse.htm

Comment: Works for both, thanks!